# Joomla 2.5 component: How to install config.xml fields values to database on installation?

Tags: php, joomla

I currently write a Joomla 2.5 component
The problem is: I have config.xml file in admin.
when I install the component, the value of config.xml file are not installed in jos_extension table with the component infor.

How to do that?

Thank you very much

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

The config.xml file is for configuration and is read on the fly when edited. The first time you make a change to your configuration in the administration area the data will be saved.

Comment: Yes I knew that, do you know how to save the content of config.xml file at the time installing the component?